# My query has stopped returning any results (related to ST_DISTANCE)

Tags: google-fusion-tables

For the past 4 months or so we've been happily using this query:

SELECT * FROM 2066206 ORDER BY ST_DISTANCE(geometry, LATLNG(51.5081289,-0.12800500000003012))

It now returns zero rows. If I change it to the following it works fine:

SELECT * FROM 2066206 ORDER BY geometry

Is there currently an issue with the ST_DISTANCE function?

This is function is documented on https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/developers_reference

The 'geometry' field is a Google location field based on our lat + lng columns. For this example the lat lng is what Google returns for "London".

Really appreciate any possible insights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be working for me now:

[http://www.google.com/fusiontables/api/query?sql=SELECT+*+FROM+2066206+ORDER+BY+ST_DISTANCE(geometry,+LATLNG(51.5081289,-0.12800500000003012))](http://www.google.com/fusiontables/api/query?sql=SELECT%20%2a%20FROM%202066206%20ORDER%20BY%20ST_DISTANCE%28geometry,%20LATLNG%2851.5081289,-0.12800500000003012%29%29)

Are you still having issues?

Comment: Thanks Kathryn. You're right it has started working again.

Pretty odd, the ST_DISTANCE function has been returning zero rows all day so something behind the Fusion Table scenes must have been fixed.